# Installing BibLatex Package via Using Docker Image File

Tags: biblatex, packages, installing, tlmgr

I have a trouble about on installing a specific LaTeX package via Docker image using `tlmgr`.

I have a Docker file as you can see below:

```
RUN tlmgr update --self 
RUN tlmgr install latexmk
RUN tlmgr install latex-bin
RUN tlmgr install collection-latex
RUN tlmgr install collection-latexrecommended

RUN tlmgr install tcolorbox
RUN tlmgr install environ
RUN tlmgr install trimspaces
RUN tlmgr install xstring
RUN tlmgr install fontaxes
RUN tlmgr install multirow
RUN tlmgr install glossaries
RUN tlmgr install glossaries-extra
RUN tlmgr install mfirstuc
RUN tlmgr install xfor
RUN tlmgr install datatool
RUN tlmgr install substr
RUN tlmgr install adjustbox
RUN tlmgr install collectbox
RUN tlmgr install xwatermark
RUN tlmgr install catoptions
RUN tlmgr install ltxkeys
RUN tlmgr install framed

RUN tlmgr install carlito
RUN tlmgr install charter
RUN tlmgr install gitinfo2

RUN tlmgr install pdfcomment
RUN tlmgr install datetime2
RUN tlmgr install tracklang
RUN tlmgr install marginnote
RUN tlmgr install soulpos
RUN tlmgr install soul
RUN tlmgr install ec
RUN tlmgr install pdftexcmds
RUN tlmgr install footmisc
RUN tlmgr install attachfile
RUN tlmgr install subfiles
RUN tlmgr install import
RUN tlmgr install picture

RUN tlmgr install pdflscape
RUN tlmgr install xcolor
RUN tlmgr install tools
RUN tlmgr install babel
```

Everything works fine with the Docker image file since I tried to add/install BibLaTeX package as: `RUN tlmgr install biblatex` but I failed. I am using an editor which has a feature that auto-completes the Docker commands even the editor cannot find that command == `RUN tlmgr install biblatex`. And actually I could not find any specific installation guide for this specific package.

Am I doing correctly? Or should I install different package such as `latex-extra` to provide BibLaTeX package?

Comment: What a nice edit, I amazed @epR8GaYuH

Answer (score 4):

I have solved that issue with typing:

```
RUN tlmgr install collection-bibtexextra
```

into the Docker image file. Hope that will help to LaTeX users.